# How to accommodate a querystring in django mock

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I'm completely stumped on this in that I don't even know what to google. I'm not well versed in python testing (I work mainly in javascript).

I have an endpoint in python/django that I added a querystring to. This is the endpoint (I've changed some names to make it more generic):

```
class ThingSeriesView(APIView):
"""
Ajax Request for just the Thing Series data
"""
renderer_classes = (JSONRenderer, )

def get(self, request, pk, **kwargs):  # pylint: disable=invalid-name
    """
    :param request:
    :param pk:
    :return:
    """
    thing = get_object_or_404(models.Thing, pk=pk)
    frequency = float(request.GET.get('frequency', '1.0'))

    serializer = ChartDataSeriesSerializer(
        thing.get_series(frequency))

    return Response(serializer.data)
```

The line I added was (and this is causing the problem):

```
frequency = float(request.GET.get('frequency', '1.0'))
```

And `thing.get_series` was originally just passed '1.0' for everything.

This is fine, and it does what I need to it to, however it breaks a test:

```
class TestThingSeriesView(object):
"""
Test the ThingSeries view
"""

def test_get(self):
    thing = models.Thing()
    # pylint: disable=line-too-long
    with patch('main.endpoints.get_object_or_404', new_callable=Mock) as mock_get_obj,\
         patch('main.endpoints.Response', new_callable=Mock) as mock_response,\
         patch.object(thing, 'get_series') as series_method:

        endpoint = endpoints.ThingSeriesView()
        mock_get_obj.return_value = thing

        assert endpoint.get(Mock, 'foo') == mock_response.return_value

        mock_get_obj.assert_called_once()
        series_method.assert_called_with(1.0)
```

This is the error I get:

```
>       frequency = float(request.GET.get('frequency', '1.0'))
E       AttributeError: type object 'Mock' has no attribute 'GET'
```

How can I rewrite the test so that a custom frequency value can be passed in? I'm guessing I need to import requests, but I don't know what to do after that.

Alternatively, am I doing something wrong in the endpoint? (which I don't think so, because it's doing what I want it to do.)

Comment: Why are you mocking everything? Django provides support for testing, did you read the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/testing/tools/) ?

Comment: I did not write the original test, so I don't know why everything is mocked. Thank you for the documentation link.

Comment: @GabrielMuj don't know if this helps, but in the integration tests for the endpoints, Client is used, but nowhere in the unit tests.

Comment: You can use request factory for unit testing your view, here is the [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/testing/advanced/#the-request-factory)

Comment: Also for your `Thing` model, just create one as usual, but use `TransactionTestCase` as your superclass for `TestThingSeriesView`. This will rollback database changes and assure test isolation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to do those mocks, remember that mocking is evil, it can hide bugs in your code, the above tests can be done without any mocking at all.

You should refactor your test to use `RequestFactory` and `TransactionTestCase`. By the way I see you are using rest framework, so you can use `APIRequestFactory` which extends `RequestFactory` from django. Something like this should work:

```
from django.test import TransactionTestCase
from rest_framework.test import APIRequestFactory
from your_models import Thing

class TestThingSeriesView(TransactionTestCase):
    """
    Test the ThingSeries view
    """
    def setUp(self):
        self.factory = APIRequestFactory()

    def test_get(self):
        thing = Thing.objects.create() # create your model here
        request = self.factory.get('thing_url') 
        response = ThingSeriesView.as_view()(request, thing.id)

        # your assertions on the response
```

Comment: As I prefaced in my question, I'm not familiar with this stuff to even Google it effectively, so I don't know the pros/cons of different approaches, let alone any approaches. I also cannot ask the person who wrote it to find out why he chose to do it the way he did, so I don't know if it was cutting corners or there was a deliberate reason (he is a generally conscientious coder, so I assume the latter).

Comment: So I've tried this, and constructed the url correctly (matches the pattern needed in urls.py), and I've created a user with make_user (which is done in other tests and works as I expect). However I'm getting a 404 in the response code and really don't know what to do next. I don't know why it's not found.

Comment: I should also mention that the frequency argument is passed in as "?/frequency=1.0" which doesn't feel like it's the right way to do it. I don't really know.

Comment: Ah sorry, you need to create the `Thing` model. I add that in the response

Comment: Yes, I have that. This is how I built the url:

`thing = models.Thing()`
`url = "/api/things/" + str(thing.id) + "/chart/rvb/?frequency=1.0"`

Comment: It completely barfs on object.create(). This is used nowhere else (and is not a method of that object, but I don't know, maybe that's a inherited method or something), but there is a factory for this object, and I'm thinking maybe that's how it's supposed to be made?

When I say 'barf' I mean that I get a `RelatedObjectDoesNotExist` error.

Comment: FINALLY. Creating the thing object with the appropriate factory works and I get a 200.

This is still a wildly divergent approach from the rest of the unit tests, so I don't know if it is appropriate (though it seems sufficiently granular to be a unit test and not an integration test) or what using Mock was intended to do.  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Use the factory to create models (I didn't know you have support for that). You can make assertions on `response.data` to see what actually it returns based on your model creation and what the view does.